# Checking Against Value From Array and Return Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've 2 arrays `A` and `B`.

Take for instance `Array A` has a field `A1`, and `Array B` has 2 fields `B1` and `B2`.

Both arrays contain the same variable - `A1, B1`

I'm trying to check the value of `Array B (B1)` against the `Section Header Text` of a `TableView`

Since `indexPath.section` and `indexPath.Row` are used in TableViews, i was hoping that i could actually use them to iterate through `Array B`.

If the value of both of the values stated above respectively are equal, i'd like to return a cell that at that instance using either `indexPath.section` ot `indexPath.Row` to retrieve the value of `Array B - Field (B2)` and that will be the cell.text that i'll be returning.

I'm helping troubles making it work.. Appreciate any help or guidance.. Thank you

Here are the codes..

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let sectionViewHeader = tableView.headerView(forSection: indexPath.section)
     let programNameSection = sectionViewHeader?.textLabel?.text
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

     let tempFullProgramName = c[indexPath.row].fullProgramName
     let tempCourseName = c[indexPath.row].courseName

     if tempFullProgramName == programNameSection {
         cell?.textLabel?.text = tempCourseName
     }

     return cell!;
}
```